# How to manage duplicate sql values that has to be unique?

Tags: sql, duplicates

Users of my site can submit `post title` and `post content` by form. The `post title` will be saved and converted to SEO friendly mode `(eg: "title 12 $" -> "title-12")`. this will be this post's url.

My question is if a user entered a title that is identical to previous entered title, the url's of those posts will be identical. So can be the new title be modified automatically by appending a number to the end of the title?

**eg:**

> "title-new" -> "title-new-1" or if  "title-new-1" present in db
>   convert it to "title-new-2"

I'm sorry I'm new to this, maybe it's very easy, Thanks for your help.

I'm using PDO.

Comment: You could create a trigger that checks `INSERT`s and `UPDATE`s.  If it finds that they have created duplicates then it can change the new titles.  Begs the question of what happens when an `UPDATE` sets _all_ of the titles to "Not Me!".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you @Ratna & @Borniet for your answers. i'm posting explained code to any other user who want's it. if there is somrthing should be added or removed or better way please let me know.

//first i'm going to search the "new unchanged title name" whether it's present in db.

```
$newtitle= "tst-title";   
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname='dbname', 'usrname', 'password');
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `col.name` = ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute(array($newtitle));
if ( $stmt->rowCount() < 1 ) {
// enter sql command to insert data
    }
else {
$i='0';
do{
$i++;
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM `tablename` WHERE `url` = ? LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute(array($newtitle.'-'.$i));
}
while($stmt->rowCount()>0);
// enter sql command to insert data
}
```

---

that's it. the reason i'm dividing in to two is  because i want to add '-' to the url instead of just number.

Answer (score 0):

when saving the post title you can query the db if it exists? If it exists the simply append a number and again query, if it again exists increment it by one and hence.

Comment: exactly. i want to know how to append it. i add a query to check whether it exists but i'm stuck there.:(

Comment: suppose your title is wha eha wha wha ie title = "wha eha wha wha"; now you query and get it exists now initialize a int a = 1, and title+=a.tostring(); again query if that also exists increment a ++; and hence

Comment: That would result in 200 queries if the title exists 200 times. Using rowCount() would only need 1 single query to know if it exists or not, and how many times.

Answer (score 0):

Do a select on your database for that title, and use rowCount() to check how many results you have. If the result is 0: you can add it, if the result is n, you add n to the title.

To append use something like this (not correct):

```
$count = $del->rowCount(); //Assuming this returns 1

if($count){
  $title = $title . "-" . $count;
}
```

This will give you "theduplicatetitle-1"

Comment: thanks, correct me if i'm wrong but if the same title used 3 times second title and third one will be equal. i need it to be incremental.

Comment: Nope :-) If it doesn't exist, $count = 0, if it exists, $count = 1, newtitle = theduplicatetitle-1, if there are 2 titles: $count = 2, newtitle = theduplicatetitle-2, if there are 3 titles: $count = 3, newtitle = theduplicatetitle-3, etcetera. You just need to cut off the number to check if the title exists.If you want to make that easier, you can save 2 titles in the database: "theduplicatetitle" and "newtitle = theduplicatetitle-1". The first one for reference, the second to use.

Comment: Assuming first title= "original-title" which exists. user adds same title and query will search for "original-title" and count will give 1 and the new title will be "original-title-1". again user adds the title "original-title" and quary will serch for "original-title" and count will again give 1 because second one is "original-title-1" so the third one also be "original-title-1". isn't it????

Comment: Yes, that's why I said to cut off the number when searching (using substr(), or saving the original title and the new title in a seperate column in your database. I would opt for the second option.